# socket.io+ Node:Object #<Namespace> has no method 'clients'

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

```
console.log(io.sockets.clients('test1234fgdgdfgdfg'));
```

**It gives me error :**
Object # has no method 'clients'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

io.sockets.clients() can no longer be used after version Socket.IO version 1.0

Here's what you should use:

```
for (var clientId in io.sockets.adapter.rooms[roomId]) {
    var clientSocket = io.sockets.connected[clientId];
}
```

Comment: how to get room id after call socket.join(data.room);

Comment: Can i get room name from room id?

Comment: You should be able to just insert your room name in for a substitute for roomId like `io.sockets.adapter.rooms['theRoomNameHere']`

Comment: after that how i get clients name from that room object.....i want to get users name whose  have join this room.

Comment: That is much more complicated. You'll need to create an interface where users can enter their name - have that passed to the server - and then have the server tag that to their clientId.